# How to display the loading progress bar on top of the dialog popup which is listview?

Tags: android, listview, dialog, progressdialog

I'm a having a listview, of type dialog pop-up. When i click on the item of the listview, i want loading progress bar to be displayed. Below is the listview code.

```
public AdapterView.OnItemClickListener getOnItemClickListener() {
        return new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
//                ProgressDialog dialog;
//                dialog = ProgressDialog.show(view.getContext(), "Please wait..", "Loading data", true);
//                dialog.setCancelable(false);
//                dialog.show();
                HashSet sometable= new HashSet();
                sometable.add(i);
                if (getContext() == null) return;
                Intent output = new Intent();
                final IData data = (IData)  adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
                //check if its myself
                if((data.get("FIRST_NAME")==null)&&(data.get("LAST_NAME")==null))
                output.putExtra("User","");
                else{
                    output.putExtra("User", (String) data.get("ASSIGNEE_GUID"));
                    output.putExtra("userName", (String) data.get("FIRST_NAME") + " " + (String) data.get("LAST_NAME"));
                    //new cancelPending((Activity) getContext(),data).execute();
                    AssigneABO.SyncSubordinateCalendar((String) data.get("ASSIGNEE_GUID"), view.getContext());
                    //new MyTask(MainActivity.this).execute((Void) null);

                }
                Activity activity = (Activity) getContext() ;
                activity.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,output);
                activity.finish();
            }
        };
    }
```

When i click on the items of the listview, starts the async task to get the data. In that async task's onprexcute method i'm calling the progress dialog as below.

```
public static class SyncApplicationTask extends AsyncTask<String, Context, Boolean> {
        Context context;
        ProgressDialog progress;// = new ProgressDialog(context);
        public SyncApplicationTask(Context mcontext) {
            super();
            context = mcontext;
            progress = new ProgressDialog(context);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            progress.setMessage(context.getString(R.string.Sync));
            progress.setTitle(R.string.sync_msg);
            progress.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            progress.setCancelable(false);
            progress.setIndeterminate(true);
            progress.show();

            if (!Util.hasActiveNetworkConnection(context)) {
                Util.alertMessageDialog(context, R.string.network_connection_unavailable_message);
             return;
            }
            if (SynchronizationManager.getInstance().isSyncAllCategoryGroupActive()) {
                Util.alertMessageDialog(context, R.string.synchronization_still_active);
                return;
            }
            if (!ConnectionManager.getInstance().isServerConnected()) {
                ConnectionManager.getInstance().stopServerConnection(60);
                boolean isStarted = ConnectionManager.getInstance()
                        .startServerConnection(60); // 2 mins time out
                Log.v("Connection started : ", Boolean.valueOf(isStarted)
                        .toString());
                if (!isStarted) {
                    Util.alertMessageDialog(context, R.string.connection_server_lost_message);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... syncGroups) {
            try {
                SAPReXDB.synchronize(syncGroups[0]);

                return true;
            }catch (Exception Ex)
            {  Log.v("Erron on sync: ", Ex.toString());
                return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean c) {
            progress.dismiss();
            if(!c)
                Util.alertMessageDialog(context, R.string.sync_progress_failed);

        }
    }
```

But it is displaying behind the dialog listview. I want it to display above the dialog listview. What am'i doing wrong. Can you please suggest me on this. Thank you.

Comment: You can try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6758800/5124783

Answer (score 1):

With which Context do you create ProgressDialog?
GUI position & order issues can happen when you do not use normal Activity Context, but using your specific View's context or Application Context.

Comment: Hello @Suhyeon, i'm listview's view to get the context like view.getContext().

Comment: @coders Can you test it with current Activity's context? By temporarily passing Activity Context or set it to public?

Comment: @coders If you use Context of the layout which is in front of list view, then progress should be shown at least.(If the position is right)

Comment: yes the progress is showing on the back of the dialog. when i click on the listview, i'm fetching some data, fetching of data is taking time. During this period, i need to display the progress dialog. Now its displaying the progress dialog. But not on top of the dialog listview.

Comment: I tried as  Activity activity = (Activity) getContext() ; activity.getApplicationContext(), no luck.. I have also tried as MyTeamSelectListView.this.getcontext() but no luck

Comment: @coders Can you provide any screenshots and the actual source code which calls SyncApplicationTask.execute()?